# Converting HttpFoundation\Response to an array

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine

My symfony request is returning array with entity object and setstate method.

This is the dump of the array.

```
array (
  0 => 
  HealthyLiving\ApiBundle\Entity\User::__set_state(array(
     'id' => 1,
     'username' => 'admin',
     'password' => '123',
     'email' => 'batoosay@gmail.com',
     'isActive' => false,
  )),
)
```

And here is the code:

```
public function loginAction()
{
  $restresult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ApiBundle:User')->findAll();
    if ($restresult === null) {
      return new View("there are no users exist", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
 }
    echo '<pre>' . var_export($restresult, true) . '</pre>';die;

   return new JsonResponse(
        $restresult
    );
}
```

The JsonResponse is empty because of the strange array. How do i convert this array of object to json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to serialize with JMS like this:

```
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

return new Response(
    $serializer->serialize($restresult, 'json')
);
```

Comment: This is what i get then "[{\u0022id\u0022:1,\u0022username\u0022:\u0022admin\u0022,\u0022password\u0022:\u0022123\u0022,\u0022email\u0022:\u0022batoosay@gmail.com\u0022,\u0022is_active\u0022:false}]"

Comment: try now I have update the answer getting the service